# Generate valid random internal IPv6 subnet for throw-away testing

Tags: c#, f#, ip, ipv6, docker.dotnet

I want to create a Docker network for testing purposes. I do not care what particular subnet I use, just that it is private and available. Since the IPv6 address space is so large, I believe that I can generate a subnet randomly and have low chance of collisions with existing subnets.

What is a procedure for generating such a subnet in .NET (*C#* or *F#* is fine)?

My initial attempt:

```ml
open System
open System.Net

let generateRandomSubnet () =
  let bytes = Array.zeroCreate 16
  let random = Random()

  random.NextBytes(bytes)

  let ipAddress = IPAddress(bytes)
  let subnet = (string ipAddress) + "/24"

  subnet
```

> c726:f7e1:ae0b:93f8:e60c:a921:8398:6a45/24
>
> 356a:6035:683c:53a6:7f60:2724:3fc0:bcbf/24
>
> 8943:dfb0:a19:b251:723b:341e:d107:9948/24

Comment: What you really want to do is use [IPv6 ULA](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193.html). You can assign addresses in the `fd00::/8` range with the next 40 bits randomly chosen to give you a `/48` prefix from which you can derive 65,536 standard `/64` IPv6 networks. There are plenty of tools, including web sites, that will generate a ULA prefix for you (off-site recommendations are off-topic here). Also, the first and last prefixes you have generated are currently invalid, so they may be problematic, and you should only use `/64` networks or you can break some IPv6 features.

Comment: Does `docker network create --subnet` understand IPv6 ULAs?

Comment: If not, then it is not standards compliant. It is RFC 4193 (the link in my previous comment), and set up by IANA for use on local networks.

Comment: Docker is open source, so you could go grab the source for that and convert to F#.